# Android: How to get DatabaseReference for user changed?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Node.js I have the following lines of code:

```
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
    var stateSnapshot = snapshot.child("state");
    if (stateSnapshot.val() != "Calm") {
        var latitudeSnapshot = snapshot.child("latitude");
        var longitudeSnapshot = snapshot.child("longitude");

        var locationSnapshot = snapshot.child("location");
        var locationReference = locationSnapshot.ref;

        var latitude = latitudeSnapshot.val();
        var longitude = longitudeSnapshot.val();
    }
}
```

This is the visualization of my database structure:
[image: Visualization of Database structure]

I need to know how to write the same code in Android. I would like something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference usersReference = database.getReference("users");

usersReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // Retrieve new posts as they are added to Firebase
    @Override
    public void onChildUpdated (DataSnapshot snapshot, String userKey){
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the exact translation, however I am not sure how ideal it is to use within android, as there are better ways to get data e.g. Model class.

```
       @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            DataSnapshot stateSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("state");
            if (!stateSnapshot.getValue(String.class).equals("Calm")) {
                DataSnapshot latitudeSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("latitude");
                DataSnapshot longitudeSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("longitude");

                DataSnapshot locationSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("location");
                DatabaseReference locationReference = locationSnapshot.getRef();

                long latitude = latitudeSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                long longitude = longitudeSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
            }
        }
```